# Correct way to have a global variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables, components

I'm developing a react.js project and before the main component is rendered, I call a function that returns an object that all components should be able to access. What is the correct way of doing this in react? Currently, I'm just passing it as a prop to the main component and then I suppose I should have to remember to pass it as a prop to all other components. Is there an easier or better way of doing this?

Comment: Searching your title, I found this possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351804/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-react

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing something like Redux. Passing the object as props should be okay. You could make a higher-order component that wraps your components and adds access to that global object via props. This is similar to Redux's `connect`.

Answer (score 0):

As the expectation in React is application-wide concerns ,like a flux/redux/apollo store, are kept in a root provider component’s context and then accessed elsewhere in the component tree via a Higher Order Component or render props. This provides relief from globals and circular dependencies, and makes testing those components easier.

However, if you have non-component code that will need access to configuration values, you may need to use `config` global and writing components in a way that accepts config values from props.

see: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config

Comment: Would it be simpler to just have an exports file or something similar with all the things I want to have available globally or is this bad practice?

Comment: Sensitive values (session secrets, database passwords, etc.) and server-only concerns should continue to be loaded via secured environment variables (better using node-config as Since node-config is a server-side module it reads files only).