# Creating a Global Prop in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I am wondering, is it possible to create a global prop in react -- i.e., a prop that works with any component (just like I can use `className` with any component)?

For example, a `flex` property that I could call on any component that would have set behavior -- like this:

```
<Header flex>...</Header>
```

In this case, it would set `display: flex;`.  This is just a theoretical example.  My question is whether or not this is possible -- and, if so, how to do it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510949/how-to-create-a-global-variable-that-can-be-accessed-in-different-component-in-r

Comment: Have a look at data attributes available in HTML5

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: @PFuster Thanks for the suggestion.  I personally don't like using data attributes.  I don't like having to put `data-` in front of every attribute.  It's just a personal style preference.