# How do I create a globally accessible variable in React JS

Tags: reactjs, variables, global

In my react JS app, I make many API calls,

Rather than having to specify:
const BASE_URL = 'https://apiurlgoeshere.com/'

on every page, I'd rather have BASE_URL accessible throughout the entire application, so I can just do BASE_URL + API_CALL for example

Comment: Did you try to use `localStorage` to save global variable?

Comment: @Jin — It's a SPA, there's no need to store it.

Comment: I would suggest providing all URLs in single page and then use that urls into different pages

Comment: okay then please try to do like this.

window.BASE_URL = 'https://apiurlgoeshere.com/';
Then you can use this variable globally.

Comment: Assuming you're using a module bundler like Webpack, create a module (e.g. `constants.js`) and import it wherever you need the constants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351804/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-react)

Comment: If this is a `create-react-app`-generated project, I suppose you could store things like that in files such as `config.js` containing `export const BASE_URL = 'https://api.example.com'` and import it in your component(s). There are many solutions to this however...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is just adding `BASE_URL`, then this can be achieved by declaring it inside a `constants.js` file and exporting it from there. But then, that makes us do `BASE_URL + "something"` each time we make a network request which isn't really ideal either. Also there might be some scenarios where other configuration have to be shared, like say, a common header that has to be added to all the requests.

To solve this, most request libraries have in-build solutions. If we are choosing [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) as the most popular one, we can [create a instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) like:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
export default instance;
```

and import this everywhere the `axios` is going to be used like:

```
import axios from "./axios-instance";
```

assuming `axios-instance.js` is the file where the instance is created. Now you can skip adding the `BASE_URL` to every request as it is already provided in the instance.

Comment: Looks interesting and probably better than React Context. Can you elaborate when you use React Context and when to use this way?

Comment: @EresDev: when React Context is [an over-engineered solution](https://dev.to/bhldev/comment/1222i).

Answer (score 1):

If `webpack` is being used for code bundle, [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) can be used.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'BASE_URL': JSON.stringify('https://apiurlgoeshere.com/')
});
```

For `gulp` build, [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) can be used.

`.pipe(replace('BASE_URL', 'https://apiurlgoeshere.com/'))`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since I created this post - just wanted to go through what I've learnt really.

It's a great way to set a global config for Axios. I typically create a folder and create an api.js file within it which I use to make all of my API calls, this is great as it means you only have to specify headers / base URL / credentials etc once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example for a solution:

```
function apiCall (method, path, data) {
    let url = "https://urltoyourapis.com/";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return Axios[method](url, {headers}, data).then(res => {
            return resolve(res);
        }).catch(err => {
            return reject(err);
        })
    })
}
```

Now, whenever you want to make an API call you'd import this function into the file where you would like to make the API call and do the following:

```
apiCall("get", "account-info")
```

This will then make an API call to the endpoint "account-info" to get the information, you can either await and set the result to a variable or use .then .catch to handle the response.