# How can I add debug functions that I can call from Chrome Debugger Console to a Create React App?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, create-react-app

I created an app with Create React App.

How can I add global debug functions (e.g. `resetDatabase()`) that I can call from Chromes Debug Console (or some other way)?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the function to the global window object, or some namespaced object.

Then in the console you can run it with:

window.resetDatabase();

Here’s a link to a relevant post about accessing the global context through the componentWillMount callback.

[How to declare a global variable in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351804/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-react)

Comment: This answer recommends to use Context, which does not seem to help here, right?

Also there is a kind of hackish answer that suggests using componentWillMount which does not look like an ideal solution to mee?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this site -: 
IT gives you the complete guide for that or if you face any issue feel free to ask
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Open the Console as a dedicated panel or as a drawer next to any other panel.
Stack redundant messages, or display them on their own lines.
Clear or persist output between pages, or save it to a file.
Filter output by severity level, by hiding network messages, or by regular expression patterns.