# Sharing sass variables globally with components in create-react-app

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I am using `create-react-app` for a new project. I have installed node-sass and everything is working. I have one `variables.scss`  file in a `styles` folder that is at the root of the `src` folder. I want to be able to use the variables in this file across all the component style files of the app.

I don't like the approach of importing the `variables.scss` file to each component's scss file. I want to be able reference the variables anywhere in the app and get the values. But so far, I have not been able to find a good resource that shows how to do this without `ejecting` `create-react-app`.

```
  - src/
      - styles/ 
        - variables.scss
      - App.js
      - App.scss
      - features/
        - home/
          - home.scss
          - Home.js
      - index.js
      - index.scss
```

For instance, if I need to use a variable in the `home.scss` file, I should not be importing the `variables.scss` file. Instead, I could just reference the name of the variable.

Please let me know what is possible.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55624363/11758901

Comment: Related to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7756)