# How to pass data from root html script into the child level components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-dom

How to access the data which is available at root level html script in react child components?

- root.html

  ```
  <html>
     <head> 
      <script type="text/javascript">           
        function DataIntoComponents()    
        {            
          var message = 'Some Data';
          //How to pass this message into the components   
        }             
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id='root'></div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- index.tsx

  ```
  componentDidMount{
   //How to access message here ??
  }
  ```

Comment: does window.message work?

Comment: Able to set window.message in root.html but Window.message is not accessible in index.tsx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a global variable in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351804/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-react)

Comment: @keikai I cannot use Context in root.html , It is a plain javascript.