# NextJS Global Variable with Assignment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, global-variables

I'm new to NextJS, and trying to figure out, how to create a global variable that I could assign a different value anytime. Could someone give a simple example? (I know global might not be the best approach, but still I would like to know how to set up a global variable).

Let's say:

**_app.js**

```
NAME = "Ana" // GLOBAL VARIABLE
```

**page_A.js**

```
console.log(NAME) // "Ana"
NAME = "Ben"
```

**page_B.js**

```
console.log(NAME) // "Ben"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a global variable in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351804/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-react)

Comment: No, but this does: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/01/using-react-context-for-state-management-in-next.js/ and this does: https://reacttricks.com/sharing-global-data-in-next-with-custom-app-and-usecontext-hook/ and also this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/react-context-api-nextjs-axel-laurent-obscura-sarzotti thanks anyways

Answer (score 5):

try using Environment Variables

***/next.config.js***

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    customKey: 'my-value',
  },
}
```

***/pages/page_A.js***

```
function Page() {
  return <h1>The value of customKey is: {process.env.customKey}</h1>
}

export default Page
```

but you can not change its contents, except by changing it directly in next.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs no special ways to provide global variables you want. You can achieve by:

1. Stateful management tool, like redux-react
2. Using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's not like it's impossible,
I created a file called `_customGlobals.jsx` and put this as content

```
String.prototype.title = function () {
  const sliced = this.slice(1);
  return (
    this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
    (sliced.toUpperCase() === sliced ? sliced.toLowerCase() : sliced)
  );
};
```

and imported it in `_app.jsx` like this:

```
import "./_customGlobals";
```

So now I can call this function on any string anywhere in my project like this:
`"this is a title".title()`